# Setting up a static IP. Please can someone explain the process

Tags: linux, networking, settings

I have just installed Linux Fedora 20 on my laptop; I have it already on my main home computer. I maintain a number of files, mostly my own notes, hints and reminders about how to do things, that I would like to synchronise so that I can edit the files on either machine. I understand that I can do this via the internet, and that one of the first steps is to give each machine a static IP.

The instructions to set a static IP seem to involve a lot of editing of special files, but I hesitate to start the process, in case I fumble it, because I do not know what is going on, and so some irrevocable damage.

There is a bewildering number of suggestions out there, but they all leave me with the feeling that I am missing something I should already know about.

So I have two related questions:

1) How do I choose a static IP, or is that created automatically as part of the process?

2) A longer one, sorry: please can someone explain the process, i.e. what is altered, and why?

---

Solved (so far)

Thank you to @mat and @Stefan Schmiedl. I have followed the process Stefan suggested and both machines nicely pinged the other. Now I must look into what to do next, but so far it's nice and easy. If I need to I will put further questions in a separate post.

I follow what mat says, but one of the troubles with programming and many other pursuits is that, to be able to ask a sensible question, you need quite a lot of previous knowledge of what is available and appropriate to what you want to do.  If you already have that knowledge, then you may not need to ask the question. References tell you the details, but you do also need to know what particular details you want to find out about.

There are two kinds of explanation: those that allow the experts to nod wisely to one another, and those that make things clear to the naive enquirer. I was after the second one, which Stefan kindly supplied

---

One more supplementary question: is this the approach to take if one machine is at home and the other is at a different location with a different internet address, router etc.? I have joined a Linux User Group that meets in council offices in another town, and would like the file synchronisation to work from there too.

Comment: You do not need a static IP to connect to the Internet. I think you should completely rethink your question, because you're looking at the wrong thing. What problems are you having connecting to the Internet? Are you using WiFi? Ethernet? What are you plugged in to? Did you follow guides/tutorials, and what errors did you get following those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that you don't have the problem you think you're having.

The "usual" home-setup nowadays is

- a local network behind
- some ISDN/DSL/whatever router

In that case, the router usually acts both as DHCP and DNS server for the local network, i.e. you could leave the network configuration as-is and try to reach the other machine by name instead of by ip.

Ask both machines for their hostnames, which should give something like

```
stefan@tuxedo ~ % hostname
tuxedo
stefan@tuxedo ~ % hostname --fqdn
tuxedo.fritz.box
```

Next try basic network connectivity by pinging the other box:

```
stefan@g128 ~ % ping -c 3 tuxedo
PING tuxedo (192.168.1.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from tuxedo-wlan.fritz.box (192.168.1.102): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.17 ms
64 bytes from tuxedo-wlan.fritz.box (192.168.1.102): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.27 ms
64 bytes from tuxedo-wlan.fritz.box (192.168.1.102): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.27 ms

--- tuxedo ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.271/1.575/2.176/0.424 ms
```

As you can see in the example, the box "g128" was able (by querying my router) to determine the IP address of "tuxedo" and the connection is good.

If you don't have that kind of setup and really have to do things by hand, it can be a bit tricky and a lot depends on the details of your setup.